# Issue On Saving Active Sheet as New Worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to save first sheet of an excel file into the Directory C: by using this code:

```
Sub SaveSheet()
    ActiveSheet.Copy
    With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        .Copy
        .PasteSpecial xlValues
        .PasteSpecial xlFormats
    End With
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:/" & Format(Range("E19"), "mmm-d-yyyy")
End Sub
```

but I am having two issues here:
First of all I do not know where to SET the new file Name?
2- I am encountering with following warning message:

[image]

while I have already enabled using Macro like:

[image]

Can you please let me know how to fix these issues?

Thansk

update:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax of `.SaveAs` is

`expression.SaveAs(FileName, FileFormat, Password, WriteResPassword, ReadOnlyRecommended, CreateBackup, AccessMode, ConflictResolution, AddToMru, TextCodepage, TextVisualLayout, Local)`

Refer to Excel Help for more details. When you are saving a workbook, the minimum of two parameters that you should specify is `FileName` and `FileFormat`

If you want to save the file as macro free file then you will have to specify the file format specifically.

For example

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\" & Format(Range("E19"), "mmm-d-yyyy") & ".xlsx", _
                      FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
```

or a more simplified approach

```
Sub SaveSheet()
    Dim FName As String

    ActiveSheet.Copy
    With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        .Copy
        .PasteSpecial xlValues
        .PasteSpecial xlFormats
    End With
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    FName = "C:\" & Format(Range("E19"), "mmm-d-yyyy") & ".xlsx"

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=FName, _
                          FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
End Sub
```

Similarly if you want to save the file with macros the above code becomes

```
Sub SaveSheet()
    Dim FName As String

    ActiveSheet.Copy
    With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        .Copy
        .PasteSpecial xlValues
        .PasteSpecial xlFormats
    End With
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    FName = "C:\" & Format(Range("E19"), "mmm-d-yyyy") & ".xlsm"

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=FName, _
                          FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
End Sub
```

Here are some commnon file formats

```
50 = xlExcel12 (Excel Binary Workbook in 2007-2013 with or without macro's, xlsb)
51 = xlOpenXMLWorkbook (without macro's in 2007-2013, xlsx)
52 = xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled (with or without macro's in 2007-2013, xlsm)
56 = xlExcel8 (97-2003 format in Excel 2007-2013, xls)
```

Comment: thanks Siddharth, the only thing that I am still confused is this macro free term? what does this mean exactly?

Comment: When you save xlsx files, it doesn't store any macros. You might want to see [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20580359/what-are-macros-in-ms-excel/20584444#20584444)

Comment: thanks, just one final thing, if iI wanna name the file for exmple TestSheet.xls where exavtly should I put it after C: ?

Comment: `FName = "C:\TestSheet.xls"`

Comment: What do you have for Fname? Cant see it. It is hidden by the dialog box

Comment: sure, FName = "C:\TestSheet.xls" & Format(Range("E19"), "mmm-d-yyyy") & ".xlsm"

Comment: Change that to `FName = "C:\TestSheet.xls"` or `FName = "C:\TestSheet - " & Format(Range("E19"), "mmm-d-yyyy") & ".xlsm"` and use the appropriate file format.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43330/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-behseini)