# How to Add Date and Time To File Name Using VBA in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

Thanks to Siddharth Rout at [this Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20632514/issue-on-saving-active-sheet-as-new-worksheet/20632628#20632628) I learned how to save a sheet to a new Worksheet. Now my question is how I can add Date and Time of file creation like:

> TestSheet_25May2013_5pm.xls

```
Sub SaveSheet()
    Dim FName As String

    ActiveSheet.Copy
    With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        .Copy
        .PasteSpecial xlValues
        .PasteSpecial xlFormats
    End With
    Application.CutCopyMode = False


    FName = "C:\Users\somebody\Documents\TestSheet" & Format(Range("E19"), "mmm-d-yyyy") & ".xlsm"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=FName, _
                          FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled



End Sub
```

can you please let me know how to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change

```
FName = "C:\Users\somebody\Documents\TestSheet" & _
        Format(Range("E19"), "mmm-d-yyyy") & ".xlsm"
```

to

```
FName = "C:\Users\somebody\Documents\TestSheet_" & _
        Format(Date, "ddmmmyyyy") & ".xlsm"
```

If you are picking the date from `Range("E19")` then ensure that the cell has a valid date.. In such a case the code becomes

```
FName = "C:\Users\somebody\Documents\TestSheet_" & _
        Format(Range("E19"), "ddmmmyyyy") & ".xlsm"
```

Comment: Glad to be of help :)

Answer (score 8):

To complete Siddharth's solution, here is the code to also include the time in the file name:

```
Function SaveDateTime() as String

    Dim SaveTime As Integer
    SaveTime = Round(Timer / 3600, 0)

    Dim AMPM As String: AMPM = "AM"
    If SaveTime >= 12 Then
        AMPM = "PM"
        If SaveTime > 12 Then
            SaveTime = SaveTime - 12
        End If
    End If

    SaveDateTime = "C:\Users\somebody\Documents\TestSheet_" & _
                    Format(Date, "ddmmmyyyy") & "_" & _
                    SaveTime & AMPM & ".xlsm"

End Function
```

Note that you could change `Round()` by `Int()` if you want the time to round down instead of just round.  And also, pay attention on the language settings on the PC you will run this on because the date format depends on it.

**Edited: Even simpler solution**

```
Function SaveDateTime() as String

    SaveDateTime = "C:\Users\somebody\Documents\TestSheet_" & _
                    Format(Date, "ddmmmyyyy") & "_" & _
                    Format(Time, "hAM/PM") & ".xlsm"

End Function
```

Answer (score 6):

I have the following working well but would like to reverse the order. File name first, date and time second. So far have not figured out a way.

```
Sub SaveToLocations()
' Saves active file to current plus two other backup locations, appends system date and time in front of file name in backup locations.

    Dim datim As String
    datim = Format(CStr(Now), "yyyy_mm_dd_hh_mm_ss_")

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs "I:\FilesBackup\" & datim & ActiveWorkbook.Name
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs "E:\CS Docs\FilesBackupCS\" & datim & ActiveWorkbook.Name
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a comment from someone who had tried and tried and tried to get the above solutions to work and then came across one little detail that makes a difference.

Depending on other code you are using you may need to use `VBA.FORMAT` to get the date to format as you may be using `FORMAT` in another context within your coding.

Only found this out after googling the question in the right way after not being able to resolve the issue for far too long and hope you never end up dealing with the same thing :)