# Excel VBA: How to point to relative directory (name of the file changes a bit everyday)?

Tags: excel, vba

The current code is:

```
Set Workbook = Workbooks.Open("Z:\test\bankinfo20180815.xls")
```

The file in the folder would change. For example: it was bankinfo20180814.xls yesterday, bankinfo20180815.xls today and bankinfo20180816.xls tomorrow. So I am wondering how I can specify in VBA code to point to the file that starts with "bankinfo"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Add Date and Time To File Name Using VBA in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20635629/how-to-add-date-and-time-to-file-name-using-vba-in-excel)

Comment: If your file name is always based on the date, then just compute the file name using the date.

Comment: Loop through files in the folder and check `LEFT([filename],8) = "bankinfo"`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
MyFile = "Z:\test\bankinfo"
Set Workbook = Workbooks.Open(MyFile & "*.xls")
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a wildcard like *, but if there are multiple files, it can open a wrong file so a better method is to make sure you are opening the exact file.

```
 Sub OpenMyWB()
    sdir = "Z:\test\"
    sFile = Dir(sdir & "bankinfo" & Format(Date, "yyyymmdd") & ".xls")
    Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(sdir & sFile)
End Sub
```